# How can i install MonoGame into Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xna, monogame

How can I install MonoGame templates for Visual Studio **2013**?

Comment: Why in the world was this down-voted?

Answer (score 15):

Assuming you want C# templates:

- Install MonoGame from [here](http://monogame.codeplex.com/)
- Find the Visual Studio templates folder (usually C:\Users[your user name]\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#)
- Copy the MonoGame folder to the Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C# folder.

Comment: Also, I needed to extract the templates and edit the *.vstemplate* file so that it refers to version 12 of *Microsoft.VisualStudio.WinRT.TemplateWizards* rather than 11. Then zip it back up and replace the original template zip with the modified version.

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATED 7 January 2014**

For people who want to use Monogame can download the 3.2 which provide the support for 2013.

The installer are available  at http://build.monogame.net/job/develop-win/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/Installers/Windows/

If you try this way you don't need to do any kind of copy-paste for project templates.

**UPDATED 9 January 14**

3.2 build have some trouble now. Check the very common issue here http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/467277

Comment: Was just trying to install MonoGame today again and I saw this post posted today, nice timing! **EDIT:** That was a quick install! I had used some complicated guides before... +1 for the help :)

Comment: You may also want to read this about editing the template: http://monogame.codeplex.com/workitem/7482

Answer (score 6):

The Paul McCowat's answer is correct.

Also, if you doesn't have visual studio 2012 in your machine, just create the folders hierarchy as he said. (C:\Users[your user name]\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#)
Then the Monogame installer can find the folder to copy the templates.

**Update**:
I don't have visual studio 2012 installed in my machine, so I had some problems to resolve in this way.

I edited some files on every template I wanted to use, searching for references of DLLs of visual studio 2012, then i changed the versions of these DLLs from 11 to 12.

Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can find a tutorial on [this](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/Tutorials) website. It is a github repository of the MonoGame project so the link should work as long as the framework is being developed.

You can also check out this 4-part tutorial on youtube.

> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FYCWl2jU0zI
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZedtwoL9_M0
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TR_JWVI2lEk
>
> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7h5uHUck79A

Answer (score 0):

Now Mono 3.4 can be downloaded for Visual Studio directly and the installer automatically installs the templates into Visual Studio. Installers are available [here](http://www.monogame.net/2015/04/29/monogame-3-4/).